# SQL - Insert into table data from another

Tags: sql

I have an issue, I want to take the value of the field 'coName' in my counties table and insert it into the 'catName' field of my categories table.

Problem is, there's 178 rows in the counties table so the following SQL doesn't quite work:

```
INSERT INTO categories
SET catName=
(
    SELECT coName
    FROM counties 
    WHERE coCountryId=201
)
```

Anybody know a way I can run this query 178 times and not duplicate the entries inserted.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
INSERT INTO categories (coname)
    SELECT DISTINCT coName
    FROM counties
```

Unless you are trying to do an update, that would be different. One important thing to note is: When you do `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT` you have to make sure you explicitly state each column and there needs to be a matching number of columns in the `SELECT` and the `INSERT`. So in this case I assumed your field in categories was `coname`...

Comment: This has worked, thanks, I'll accept answer when it lets me in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO categories
(catName)
(SELECT DISTINCT coName FROM counties)
```